# Sandboxing TideSDK application

Tags: macos, app-store, appstore-sandbox, tidesdk

I try to submit application with TideSDK 1.2.0.RC6e to App Store. But after signing code with entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- Activates the sandbox, required. -->
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- Allow your application read/write access to the user downloads folder -->
    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- Allow your application read/write access to the file selected by the user. -->
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- Allow your application to initiate network requests -->
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- Allow your application to listen for network requests -->
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <!-- Allow your application to use the printer -->
    <key>com.apple.security.print</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

application crashes with report

```
Callnote Premium(2618) deny forbidden-sandbox-reinit

Process:         Callnote Premium [2618]
Path:            /Users/administrator/Projects/CallnoteMakeup/dist/Callnote Premium.app/Contents/MacOS/Callnote Premium
Load Address:    0x1000
Identifier:      callnote-pro
Version:         2.0.4 (2.0.4)
Code Type:       i386 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [121]

Date/Time:       2012-10-15 13:19:04.024 +0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C54)
Report Version:  8

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x934c561e __mac_syscall + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x96cbdbf1 dispatch_once_f + 57
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x90121641 _xpc_runtime_set_domain + 218
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x90120a39 _libxpc_initializer + 529
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x916dac30 libSystem_initializer + 152
5   dyld                            0x8fe99cda ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 230
6   dyld                            0x8fe99fde ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 64
7   dyld                            0x8fe96268 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 356
8   dyld                            0x8fe961cc ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 200
9   dyld                            0x8fe961cc ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 200
10  dyld                            0x8fe960ba ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 62
11  dyld                            0x8fe87e05 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 211
12  dyld                            0x8fe8badb dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 3050
13  dyld                            0x8fe87376 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 704
14  dyld                            0x8fe87077 _dyld_start + 71

Binary Images:
    0x8fe86000 -         0x8feb8e57  dyld (210.2.3) <23516BE4-29BE-350C-91C9-F36E7999F0F1> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x9011c000 -         0x90139fff  libxpc.dylib (140.41) <1BFE3149-C242-3A77-9729-B00DEDC8CCF2> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x916da000 -         0x916dafff  libSystem.B.dylib (169.3) <81C58EAB-0E76-3EAB-BDFD-C5A6FE95536F> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x934b1000 -         0x934cbffc  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.18.24) <C17D49D0-7961-3B67-B443-C788C6E5AA76> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x96cbc000 -         0x96cceff7  libdispatch.dylib (228.23) <86EF7D45-2D97-3465-A449-95038AE5DABA> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
```

Is there any possibility to submit TideSDK application to App Store?

Comment: It would be good to work through this together. For apple app store, it is also important that the SDK be build with specific args since it may otherwise fail Apple's scanning process on 'private apis'. In  1.3.0, we are building what will be eventually known as TideSDK Lite that is built from the system WebKit. TideSDK Lite is a special flavor of TideSDK from the same sources.

Comment: Btw, TideSDK Lite is 'Lite' since that version would have no support for python, ruby, or php languages. As you may be aware, it is the custom WebKit build we use in TideSDK together with our Tide module and libtide that provide the ability to use these languages.